# Wait for popup result on link click before executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, confirm

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I would like all links with an attribute `data-confirmation` to display a custom confirm box before executing.
Those links can be `ajax` links with different `data-ajax-success` attributes like this one:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="OnAjaxError" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="OnAjaxSuccess(data, "updatePanel")" href="/Controller/Action/2cda26be-e6d9-416b-ae5a-ec85280fb1da"></a>
```

Or simple links like this one:

```
<a href="/OtherController/OtherAction/3ebdb11e-7994-424c-9818-6c577e56c7af"></a>
```

Thus I would like a method that would be able to wait for the popup result and continue the execution with the correct parameters (especially `data-ajax-success` and `data-ajax-failure` for ajax links).
I think this would look like something like that:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]), *[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]) a',
    function (event) {
        //pause the event

        ShowYesNoPopup("My title", "My content",
            function () {
                //continue event
            },
            function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

With the `ShowYesNoPopup`:

```
function ShowYesNoPopup(title, content, yesCallback, noCallback) {
$("#popupOuterContainer").empty();
$('<div id="popupContainer"></div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    appendTo: "#popupOuterContainer",
    closeText: '',
    buttons:{
        "yes":{
            text:'Ok',
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                yesCallback();
            }
        },
        "no":{
            text:'Cancel',
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                noCallback();
            }
        }
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $("body").css({ overflow: "hidden !important" })
    },
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        $("body").css({ overflow: '' })
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-title").html(title);
        $(this).html(content);
    }
});
}
```

I read lots of topics on this subjects but could not find one working in this particular situation. I tried to prevent the propagation before calling the popup, but then was not able to call the event again on popup `ok` button...
Some answers also said that this is was not possible and that javascript `confirm` was the only option to achieve that.

Is there a way in this case ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot.

***UPDATE***

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]), *[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]) a',
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (should_do_ajax) {
        func_callback = function() {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var successCallback = $(this).data("ajax-success");
            var failureCallback = $(this).data("ajax-failure");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                success: //what should I put here ? Because successCallback I retrieved from the link is a string, not a real function I think
                error: //same issue
            });
        }
    } else {
        func_callback = function() {
            link = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location = link;
        }
    }

    ShowYesNoPopup("My title", "My content",
        func_callback,
        function () {
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `ShowYesNoPopup` function has finished (and it happen immediately after the call to `dialog()` your code goes back to the `click` event, and unless you will call `event.preventDefault()` - the default behavior of your action will be triggered (which in your case is trigger the link-click, which cause the browser to change to that page).

What you can do use start with preventing the default behavior, and make sure that the `yesCallback` is a function that emulate this behavior (for example - `window.location = $(this).attr('href')` )

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]), *[data-confirmation]:not([data-confirmation=""]) a',
    function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (should_do_ajax) {
            func_callback = function() {
                $.ajax({
                 ...
                });
            }
        } else {
            func_callback = function() {
                link = $(this).attr('href');
                window.location = link;
            }
        }


        ShowYesNoPopup("My title", "My content",
            func_callback,
            function () {
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

You should probably change the content of the `yesCallback` function according to the `data-*` values you have (ajax call/something else).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I actually read some solutions like this one but I precisely don't know to adapt it for ajax links. How coud I write the `yesCallback` to be sure that the ajax `success` and `failure` will be correctly called if the link is an ajax one ?

Comment: Updated the answer with the relevant example, I think now it is more clear.

Comment: Thanks, it is very kind of you, I think I know what to do with `should_do_ajax` but my last interrogation is how to call `success` and `failure` callbacks, because what I will retrieve from the link with `$(this).data("ajax-success")` will be string, am I wrong ? Is there a way to call it anyway ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I updated the first post, and I hope that I am not missing something too simple : (

Comment: Not too simple, but yes - you are missing something. the `this` variable inside the `func_callback` function is not the same `this` that you want. You can use `var that = this;` inside the `function (event) {` and later on to use `that`.

Comment: Indeed I did not think about that. But I still don't know what to put in the `$.ajax({` `success:` and `failure:`, even using `that` instead of `this`. Could you please tell me what you would put in `success:` or `failure:` ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to happen on success/failure, so I really don't know :) (but it will be nice if you vote/accept the answer, as I think the current answer is correct based on your question).

Comment: I don't know either, the main question was precisely about how to achieve a kind of generic function, notably able to retrieve ajax `success` and `failure` callbacks from the clicked element. I can not write a specific function for each link :) Right now I don't know how to complete your solution so that it continues the ajax execution correctly, may be this is just not possible, but I will investigate this particular point. Thanks anyway, I'll accept.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "retrieve ajax `success` and `failure` callbacks from the clicked element" - how exactly do get these callbacks from the clicked element?